# better Data structure to map function with multiple parameters(keys)

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I always encountered a case: mapping two objects to the third object. It is like the function f(x,y) = z. Sometimes, the variable list would be even longer.

A direct implementation for this concept is a function like:

```
object myFun(Object x, Object y){
    if(x==xVal1 && y== yVal1){
         return zVal1;
    }else if(x==xVal2 && y== yVal2){
         return zVal2;
    }else if(){ }else if(){
    }
}
```

This implementation only works when the size of candicant values for the *x* and *y* is small.

Are there some better data structure design for this one. The implementation above implementation would be impossible (also not elegant) when the combination space for the values of the *x* and the *y* increases.

The Array and Map were considered at the begging. But I was unable to resolve the way that two-index keys problem since the both *x* and *y* determine an value.

Comment: would you please tell me exactly what do you wanna achieve?

Comment: you can use a pair as the key for the Map. `std::map<std::pair<Object,Object>, Object>`. For the situation above, you actually dont need it as in your example both `x` and `y` should have the same value. So check if `x` and `y` are same value, if yes, just use `x` to retrieve data from map

Comment: @knightrider, may be your comment would be work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data structure to store a data using two keys and then retrieve it using same two keys why are you reinventing the wheel use MultiHashMap of Apache Commons Collection library

ref https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html

Comment: Thanks. MultiHashMap  is not suitable, as MultiHashMap is key=>Collection. Also, only the class in the Java/lang package is allowed in my program (3rd party is available here)